# Azure Cloud Service won't write Worker Role Logs to WADLogsTable

Tags: c#, .net, azure, logging

I have an logging problem on Azure Cloud Service which has Web Role and Worker Role.
The service write Web Role's Logs to WADLogsTable. But won't write Worker Role's one.

The other day, when this problem happened, I removed the deployment and retried to deploy same package. Then the service was writing worker role's logs normally.

However, I don't know the root cause. Please tell me the solution strategy.

Thanks.

Comment: It was solved.
The wrong application insights configurations prevented the service from logging.
I got rid of the application insights from my sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading the package for the work role isn't enough.  You can either use the Visual Studio Publish functionality or the following powershell script...

```
$wadcfgxPath = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\{relative Path to your}\workerRole.wadcfgx"
echo Applying $wadcfgxPath to Your worker role 
Add-AzureAccount
$storage = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName aStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey yourStorageAccountKey
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName workRoleServiceName -StorageContext $storage -Role workerRoleName -Slot Production -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $wadcfgxPath
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your speedy response. 
I set the diagnostics extension from powershell. But won't write it.
Then I've tried to deploy using VS Publish functionality. So it's good.

Because I need to deploy using powershell, I'll compare the good extension xml with bad one.

In my source, the worker role programs are running in web role(worker and web role are in web role). I think this causes the problem...

I'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: @KUBOTAHikari your english is fine, better than my japanese